# Passing a variable using Regex into document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, string, variables

i'm attempting to pass a variable `HostOne_${Results.SubSysID.replace(/\./g,"")})` which returns a uniquie ID for each JSON entry which goes through the loop. this works for creating an element ID and onclick values. i'm attempting to complete the below:

```
if (Results.HostOneStatus = "Running")
{
  var a  = "HostOne_"${Results.SubSysID.replace(/\./g,"")}
   console.log(a);
  document.getElementById(a).className = "btn btn-xs btn-success";
}
```

This should return for example if the Value for SubsysID is "14.99.304", "HostOne_1499304", then to change the class of this element. I'm suspecting it may be something as simple as how the variable is defined.

For referance, the ID creates successfully for the below:

```
<button id="HostOne_${Results.SubSysID.replace(/\./g,"")})"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It;s hard to find solution with this Q data. Please post base html and what value print this variable "HostOne_" also this line is not correct "var a  = "HostOne_"${Results.SubSysID.replace(/\./g,"")}" ! Put error log from browser for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use concatenation:

```js
var Results ={ 
  SubSysID: '1.2.2.3'
};
var a = "HostOne_" + Results.SubSysID.replace(/\./g, "");
console.log(a);
document.getElementById(a).className = "btn btn-xs btn-success";
```

```css
.btn.btn-xs.btn-success{
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<button id="HostOne_1223">click</button>
```

Comment: @Ashaw glad to help :)